# Стоит ли добавлять к ответам и вопросам ru.so заголовок/summary на английском языке?

Tags: обсуждение

Стоит ли добавлять описание и заголовок на английском языке для того, чтобы ответ/вопрос появлялся в результатах поиска в глобальных поисковиках?

В какой форме стоит добавлять такую мета-информацию?

Comment: А зачем, если для английского языка есть английский SO?

Comment: @andreymal вопрос/ответ задан/дан на ru.so

Comment: ru.so создавался специально чтобы был русский язык, зачем тут английский ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Лучше создайте такой же вопрос на enSO и сделайте ассоциацию (если такого вопроса там ещё нет).

Comment: @andreymal потому что вопрос/ответ не найден в англоязычном сегменте и, допустим, хочется сообщить о нем англоязычным коллегам

Comment: @nörbörnën значит создайте такой же вопрос на enSO и сделайте ассоциацию

Comment: @EOF хороший ответ на мой вопрос. а ru.so при этом совсем не трогать?

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под "не трогать"? Создаете вопрос на ruSO, потом постите этот же вопрос (но переведённый на английский) на enSO. Ну и делаете ассоциацию.

Comment: под "не трогать" я имел ввиду "не добавлять англоязычную мета-информацию".

Comment: Да, не трогать:)

Comment: [[tag:не-трогать]] ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Как правильно ответил @Victor VosMottor:

> Лучше сделайте ассоциацию

[@EOF](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11266/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC-ru-so-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-summary-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7/11268#comment48084_11266)

> Лучше создайте такой же вопрос на enSO и сделайте ассоциацию (если
> такого вопроса там ещё нет)

в комментариях к вопросу на RuSO сделайте ссылку на вопрос EnSO

`ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62076359/7394871`

**Не важно**, где появился первый вопрос. Они будут связаны.

- На EnSO это будет синий шильдик (после проводки ассоциации) с текстом на русском языке и ссылкой на  русскоязычный вопрос
- На RuSO  необходимо добавить **атрибуты лицензии** в тело вопроса и
  ответа ссылки

`<sub>`Свободный перевод вопроса [«заголовок вопроса»](ссылка на вопрос) от участника  [@имя автора](ссылка на профиль).`</sub>`

`<sub>`Свободный перевод  [ответа](ссылка на ответ) от участника  [@имя автора](ссылка на профиль).`</sub>`

Comment: привет, скажи, в вопросе [тынц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1271813/2659) я правильно проставил "ассоциацию"?

Comment: @nörbörnën исправил пример. Ссылка должна быть кликабельной. Проще всего кликнуть пр. кл. мышки на `share` под ассоциированным вопросом EnSO и скопировать ссылку после слова ассоциация: в комментарии под вопросом RuSO

Comment: спасибо________

Answer (score 7):

Считаю, что, нет, не надо. Для вопросов на английском есть enSO. Это же русскоязычное сообщество. Здесь это не нужно. Лучше сделайте ассоциацию.